# NodeJS - RESTful API - Python/JSON - Trigger

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, rest, mean

I'm working on a little project - completely new to this stuff - and hope you can help me out.

On the base of this project https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4 which is up running and works really great.

The main goal is it to send a UserID over the network - which is already working by python/json - and let the server react on this and show a login with the just sent UserID and an password input.

I already enhanced the server.js with a POST from the python script and when the server is running the terminal recognizes when the UserID is sent.

```
...
    router.route('/bears/:id')

      .get(function(req, res) {
        Bear.find({‚id': req.params.id}, function(err, bear) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            console.log(‚here i am ...');
        });
    });
...
```

I also created a HTML which I thought should always listen (by AJAX) to the post and if the trigger (UserId) is send it should forward to another side with the input field.

So right now I don't really know how to implement that the Server already got the trigger and the HTML forwards the User to the Login?

Comment: You shouldn't need to listen to for anything on the client side - the client should send the URI to the server, and then the server can redirect them to wherever they need to be. What you want is to redirect the client to a login screen, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Let the server handle where the user goes - issuing a 200 for a successful user, or an error 400 if it's a bad request. For example:

```
router.route('/bears/:id')

.get(function(req, res) {
    Bear.find({‚id': req.params.id}, function(err, bear) {
        if (err)
            res.status(400).send(err);    //Send a generic bad request error
        else {
            res.status(200).render('login', { name: req.params.id }); //Direct client to your login page (this example uses the jade template egine)
    });
});
```

I hope this is what you're looking for :)

Comment: Thx for your quick response. I actually wanted to have a client on the one side which tells the server the UserID and if it is a valid user another client (with more hardware power) should wait for that trigger and then load the login page.